# Books for OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Does anyone know if there are any books on OpenCV and Python?

I have OReilly Learning OpenCV book but its for **C** so I'm looking for books/pdfs/online tutorials specifically Python and OpenCV.

I've looked at http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv was a helpful but I prefer having a book to work from.

Comment: A quick google/amazon search will lead you to MANY results for both of these im sure. (I am positive about Python books)

Comment: @PsychicOak I mean learning OpenCV with Python

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE (10/11/2013)**

Now an official tutorial on OpenCV-Python is available at opencv website. It covers almost most of important functions of OpenCV-Python API. `This tutorial is using OpenCV 3.x version`. *(So some tutorials may not be compatible with OpenCV 2.x)*

Visit : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

---

**First Answer (20/5/2012)**

There is not much tutorials on OpenCV and Python. Official ones are just the documentation and samples that come with opencv. But even some samples are difficult to understand for beginners.

And if you are specifically searching for books, no dedicated books on this topic until now. But I have seen a book with a single chapter on this topic. "Programming Computer Vision with Python" is that book. You can get a draft of that book here: http://programmingcomputervision.com/

I too felt this difficulty due to lack of Python tutorials for opencv. So I had to read other language books, then convert code to python. You too can do that, it is not a difficult task.

That is the reason I made a blog on this topic. You can visit it ( if you hadn't already) : [www.opencvpython.blogspot.com.](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2011/04/welcome-to-opencv-python.html)

There isn't much article in it right now, since I was busy. But within two months, I will be uploading more articles. And you can have some suggestions there on what tutorials you need. I will post them, if I know it.

Other tutorials, which are scattered over internet on different topics:

1) https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV2-Python : Contain some samples using new `cv2` interface. Also contain some C++ codes from official OpenCV tutorials converted to Python. So you use the official explanation along with Python code

2) https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python : contain some examples for color tracking, contours etc. Uses old `cv` interface

3) https://github.com/jessicaaustin/robotics-projects/tree/master/opencv-tutorial - contain codes for thresholding,contours etc.

4) http://pythonimage.blogspot.in - generally python image processing,  contains some OpenCV also.

Above are few, remaining you can find out by googling. But all will have less tutorial. I recommend you to check other language sites and books and convert them to Python.

Comment: nice summary. please check also [pycvlab](https://github.com/mpenkov/pycvlab) which might be helpful when you test your algo with highgui in python

Answer (score 2):

So here is a tutorial i have found, however i cannot be completely sure this is what you are looking for, as i have never used OpenCV: http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv . and here is a reference site: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html . Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but yip I've looked at that neuroforge tut before.

Comment: would you mind editing your question to tut's you have seen already? :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are many and soon growing  python examples in the source code under /samples/python