# How to install opencv in EPD?

Tags: python, image-processing

There is no opencv in EPD 7.3.1. My EPD path is like  /usr/epd

I have installed opencv using the method below the dashed line successfully .

Now cv2.so and cv.py are made in the directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

But since  my default python is epd, there is a path problem now. I copy cv2.so and cv.py  to /usr/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Now I can import cv2 under epd.

I am afraid there is a hidden trouble some day. Is my method right?

---

I just follow the link [opencv install](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)

Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake, Using the Command Line
1.
Create a temporary directory, which we denote as , where you want to put the generated Makefiles, project files as well the object files and output binaries.

2.
Enter the  and type

cmake []

For example

cd ~/opencv

mkdir release

cd release

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..

3.
Enter the created temporary directory () and proceed with:

make

sudo make install

Comment: There is another distribution you can use which has opencv included plus all of these.  http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html Download link here. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/  or you can download it through the Enthought's canopy program (cost is involved but how much is your time worth)

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a number of interfaces to opencv.  Have you tried: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html  or [OpenCV 2.4.3 and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381574/opencv-2-4-3-and-python)

Comment: i tried and found nither way was convenient. In fact I need to use inpaint .My system is 32bit linux and python is from EPD 7.3  .Is it necessary to install opencv ?

Comment: Yes if you want to use opencv's inpaint method you'll need to install it. Unless you can already do import cv2.

Comment: I can import cv2 and help(cv2) successfully now.But is my method right?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary directory is `release`.

Run the following script:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

And just type `make` command in terminal.